# Google map background not displayed in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Google maps background is not displaying in my device/emulator.
First i created
1. Certificate fingerprint MD5 (SHA1).
2. [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console)
 under services- Google Maps Android API v2 and Places API is activated
3.I got the API key, i placed api key in my layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:apiKey="Api key from google"
  android:clickable="true" />
```

Manifest file
    
      
      
      
      
         
         ...

the maps look like this. 
[The Map image on a emulator. (Evernote note shared link not spam)](http://www.evernote.com/shard/s283/sh/e6d013b7-718b-4e0b-9ccd-40c14a038ff8/ad06a6effdb98bf8c0ee433e8d1c8648)

Comment: Might this will help you see here http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/07/google-map-android-api-v2-with-location.html

Comment: http://www.evernote.com/shard/s283/sh/c8a28bb8-552f-4b63-b32b-0fe01346afc3/a81b580afd0c572b53701e87750db3e0

Comment: First import the google map library project in your eclipse workspace after try to add this library

Comment: MapTile is not loading from google maps

Comment: http://www.evernote.com/shard/s283/sh/88e90a2a-6093-4d11-82f7-3fb79c9359f2/ad299051363c75eba4ddce4eb2d99d2d

Answer (score 1):

To use google Map Service,

Please visit [code.google.com](http://code.google.com) and get you ApiKey.

create a project there->go to services->Activate the Google Maps Android API v2. Then Create Key for your application.

Add the following permissions to your manifest.

```
uses-permission android:name="com.anchit.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Use

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="your_apikey" />
```

also add following in your application tag in manifest

```
 android:name="com.anchit.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google Map V2, then your xml declaration is wrong.

New Google api need below code:

Google Map apiV1 is deprecated and you cant create new key for map api V1, only older exisiting keys are working not newer one. So try with this new things.